# Randomized QuickSort with double linked lists

Tags: c, list, sorting, quicksort, partitioning

I am trying to implement the randomized quicksort algorithm to work with double linked lists and I am doing something wrong. For some reason the `randomizedQuickSortList()` recalls itself 32369 times and then I get a segmentation fault at the first line of `randomizedPartitionList()`, whatever that is (I've even tried to write a simple `printf()`). Running it in the debugger I noticed that after a certain point the values of `p` and `r` (in `randomizedPartitionList()`)are always 1 and 2 rispectively.

I am sure that all the other functions work correctly, and I think that also the `randomizedPartitionList()` function works perfectly since I've tried it in combination with other algorithms

```
int randomizedPartitionList(node** head, int p, int r){
    int s = rand() % (r-p) + p;
    swapNodes(head, findNode(head, s), findNode(head, r)); //the indices of the findNode() function start from 1
    int x = (*findNode(head, r))->key; //the findNode() function returns a virable of type node**
    int i = p-1;
    int j;
    for(j=p; j<r; j++)
        if((*findNode(head, j))->key <= x){
            i++;
            swapNodes(head, findNode(head, i), findNode(head, j));
        }
    swapNodes(head, findNode(head, i+1), findNode(head, j));
    return (i+1);
}

void randomizedQuickSortList(node** head, int p, int r){
    if(p<r){
        int q = randomizedPartitionList(head, p, r);
        randomizedQuickSortList(head, p, q);
        randomizedQuickSortList(head, q, r);
    }
}
```

Comment: A [mcve] would be useful. We can’t be sure the other parts are working perfectly even if they seem to work elsewhere and it is always useful to have the exact input conditions to determine what’s happening in the case where it’s not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is a variation of Lomuto partition scheme, which should return an index to the now sorted in place pivot element, which is then excluded in the recursive calls (otherwise stack overflow could occur, which appears to the issue):

```
        randomizedQuickSortList(head, p, q-1);
        randomizedQuickSortList(head, q+1, r);
```

The code for findnode and swapnodes isn't included. I'm assuming that findnode locates a node by index.

---

The code could be sped up in the partition loop, since both i and j are incremented sequentially:

```
int randomizedPartitionList(node** head, int p, int r){
    int s = rand() % (r-p) + p;
    swapNodes(head, findNode(head, s), findNode(head, r)); //the indices of the findNode() function start from 1
    int x = (*findNode(head, r))->key; //the findNode() function returns a variable of type node**
    int i = p-1;
    int j;
    node* inode = *findNode(head, p);
    node* jnode = inode;
    for(j=p; j<r; j++){
        if((jnode->key <= x){
            i++;
            swapNodes(head, inode, jnode);
            inode = nextNode(inode);   // new function
        }
        jnode = nextNode(jnode);       // new function
    }
    swapNodes(head, inode, jnode);
    return (i+1);
}
```

Comment: Oh you're right, I got a bit confused given that I had implemented the algorithm using arrays and I had done it with a different syllogism, so I had to try these changes. Also many thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @AntonisPetropoulos - note that a [bottom up merge sort for a linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists) would be faster. Faster still, copy the list to an array, sort the array, create a new sorted linked list.

Comment: Thank you very much! At this point that's what we are asked to do at the university, so I have to do it that way. In fact, in the past we had to demonstrate that merge sort behaves better than other sorting algorithms (after a given dimension) and then create a hybrid algorithm that uses some elements from merge sort and some others from insertion sort and then demonstrate that this one works even better than merge sort, so in general I understand the differences   between these sorting algoritms. Again, thanks a lot for the suggestions!

Comment: @AntonisPetropoulos - I don't know if this would be accepted in your class, but an alternative to swapping nodes would create 3 lists for each instance of quicksort, nodes < pivot, nodes == pivot, nodes > pivot, moving elements from the current sub-list being partitioned into the 3 lists, and using recursion on the two lists != pivot.